# explicit template code generation in object file

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, object-files

If I have a template function in a seperate compile unit (which produces an object file with suffix .o from the CUDA C compiler NVCC)

lets say we have the definition (implementation)

```
template<typename T> 
void foo(T a){
   // something
}
```

To produce the explicit code in the object file to be able to link to it from another compilation unit I need to explicit instantiate this template (for all template parameters I need) this:

```
template void foo<double>(double a);
template void foo<float>(double a);
```

Doing this results in actual code in the object file.

Doing the other thing like:

```
template<> void foo<double>(double a);
template<> void foo<float>(float a);
```

Does not produce code in the object file, because this is a **full spezialized template declaration**. Is this correct?

Also

```
void foo(double a);
void foo(float a);
```

does not produce code because this would be a **overload declaration** ? is this correct?

The question is now, what is the general syntax to make the compiler produce code for a template function or class in a separate compilation unit?

Comment: Your full specialized template declaration is just a *declaration*. There is no definition there, hence there is no code. It is not an instantiation. (This is unrelated with CUDA btw).

Comment: You are correct that it doesn't "produce code". To "produce code" when compiling a separate compilation unit you need to have access to the template declaration and definitions at compile-time (not link time), from here all the discussion about templates in headers or explicit instantiations. So to have the compiler produce code for a template function or class **when compiling** another compilation unit you need to have access to declaration/definition and then **use it** or **explicitly instantiate it** into that unit. Always firmstanding the ODR.

Answer (score 3):

In laymans terms, when you write this:

```
template void foo<double>(double a);
template void foo<float>(double a);
```

You are explicitly telling the compiler to *instantiate* the function template with the correct template arguments, so you get an implementation of `foo<double>` and `foo<float>` just as if you had copy pasted the code from the function template and replaced `T` with `double` and `float`.

On the other hand, when you write this:

```
template<> void foo<double>(double a);
template<> void foo<float>(float a);
```

You are telling the compiler that `foo<double>` and `foo<float>` are *completely* different things that have no relation whatsoever with `foo<T>`. This is called *specialization*. However, you are not providing a *definition* for these specializations, only declarations: you are merely telling the compiler that *these things exist*, but not *what they are*. A definition of a specialization would look like this:

```
template<>
void foo<double>(double a) {
    // something else
}
```

Depending on your intent, you may want to either:

- Use explicit instantiation (if `foo<double>` and `foo<float>` share the same implementation)
- Use different specializations, while providing actual *definitions* for these specializations.

I am guessing you want the first.